# How to create a GUI to add two numbers from different two checkboxes?

Tags: python, checkbox

```
from tkinter import *
from ProjectHeader import *

def sel1():
    return 1

def sel2():
    return 2

def sel3():
    return 3

def sel4():
    return 4

def sel():

      selection = "THe answer is: " + str(sel2() + sel3())
      label.config(text = selection)

top = Tk()
var = IntVar()

CheckVar1 = sel1()
CheckVar2 = sel2()
CheckVar3 = sel3()
CheckVar4 = sel4()

C1 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Option1", variable = CheckVar1)
C2 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Option2", variable = CheckVar2)
C3 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Option3", variable = CheckVar3)
C4 = Checkbutton(top, text = "Option4", variable = CheckVar4)

B = Button(top, text ="ADD", command=sel)

B.pack()

C1.pack()
C2.pack()
C3.pack()
C4.pack()

label = Label(top)
label.pack()


top.mainloop()
```

As title said, How to create a GUI to add two numbers from different two check boxes?

for example, when I check both option 2 and option 3, the program will obtain the values in sel2() and sel3() and do the addition

I tried to do it in a few ways, but I don't understand how to make the check box to be true/ to be select when I check the box, result the code show the answer even if the boxes are not checked

thank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your program that should answer your question, if I am understanding it correctly:

```
from Tkinter import *

gui = Tk()

#create variables to store check state
checked1 = IntVar()
checked2 = IntVar()
#create values for the two boxes
cb1 = 5
cb2 = 10

#create a callback for our button
def callback():
    print(checked1.get()*cb1+checked2.get()*cb2)

c1 = Checkbutton(gui, text='b1', variable=checked1)
c2 = Checkbutton(gui, text='b2', variable=checked2)
b1 = Button(gui, text="ADD", command=callback)

c1.pack()
c2.pack()
b1.pack()

gui.mainloop()
```

You are reaching a level of complexity here in your program that it would be beneficial to restructure your gui into a class.  Read the [Tkinter documentation](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm) if you want examples of how to do this.  Here is an example with the GUI as a custom class:

```
from Tkinter import *

class Gui(object):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.top = parent

        self.checked1 = IntVar()
        self.checked2 = IntVar()

        self.c1_value = 1
        self.c2_value = 2

        self.c1 = Checkbutton(self.top, text='b1', variable=self.checked1)
        self.c2 = Checkbutton(self.top, text='b2', variable=self.checked2)
        self.b1 = Button(self.top, text="ADD", command=self.callback)
        self.l1 = Label(self.top)

        self.c1.pack()
        self.c2.pack()
        self.b1.pack()
        self.l1.pack()

    def callback(self):
        value = self.c1_value*self.checked1.get() + self.c2_value*self.checked2.get()
        self.l1.config(text=str(value))

root = Tk()

my_window = Gui(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: thank, it's really helpful :3 And I have a question, can I use input function such as int(input(...." in gui? I am taking python class in college, but I feel many thing I have learn can't relate to the GUI, for example, there have entry which represent as a input in entry.

Comment: @user47103 No, the input() function is only for getting information via command line.  If you want to get input from a Tkinter gui, you need to set up an Entry widget: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm